# How frequent should event handler be run in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

We have an App that allow user to place an order, but for every order that is unpaid we only want to keep it for 3 days and after 3 days we update the state to close, firing a request from the client side to make the update when countdown time complete would require the client machine to be on allways so we diceded to use MYSQL Event Handler, now since an order can be created anytime and as such we can't have a fixed time to which we update the status we can only update the status of those order which already pass 3 days so this require we fire the event handler at least every 1 minute to check for anyone with expire time and update the status but my fear is will this cause a memory leakage? firing event every single minute? below is the event handler code

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; -- enable event scheduler.
SELECT @@event_scheduler;  -- check whether event scheduler is ON/OFF
CREATE EVENT update_status  -- create your event
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MINUTE  -- run every 1 minute
    DO
      UPDATE order set status='1'
```

if this will cause a memory leakage what then is the best approach to issues like this? will running a cron job from inside php be a better options as well? any idea on this will be appreciated.

Comment: I would definitely use a cronjob over this. I keep logic out of the database and in the code.

Comment: Instead of using `status` you could use a time/date field which indicates when the order will expire. Then you don't need to check it every minute. When you fetch the order you simply check the expire time/date against the current time/date.

Comment: *"this require we fire the event handler at least every 1 minute"* - Why every **minute**?  Why not every **day**?  For example, every night at midnight you can have a process which checks for records that have exceeded the 3-day timeframe and cleans them up.

Comment: @David, let say a user play order at 8:00 and another user place order at 16:00 same day now the order for the first user should expire 8:00 3 days later while that of second use should expire 16:00 3 days later now if we fix a time for update say 20:00 that means first user order already expired 12 hours before the update will take place and after an order already expire we won't want the user to be able to continue with the order again but which they can still do between the 12 hours that the order has expired

Comment: limit the number of rows, that are update, for example exclude every column that has status already on 1 or was editrd the last 5vmuntes or so

Comment: @KIKO Software, ok this is making sense as well then i will only retrive those that hasn't expire but also needed to update the status for because an order could be unpaid, paid, or even closed and we would want the status to be close if the payment wasn't completed in 3 days so an update to the status field would still be required anyway

Comment: Well, then you should update the status field when the order gets paid or closed. My point is that there's no need to check all the orders in the database every minute to see if their status has changed.

Comment: @sam: And how strict is this requirement that the order must expire in *exactly* 72 hours, down to the exact minute, rather than simply expire "after 3 days"?  It's certainly possible that there is such a requirement, but the product owner should be made aware that such a requirement comes at a cost.  Executing this cleanup operation every minute of every day is potentially costly for resources.  The question seems primarily concerned with the performance of this, and to that end one option to address this concern could simply be to address the underlying requirement driving it.

Comment: *my fear is will this cause a memory leakage* Don't be afraid of this. If you'll use correct UPDATE query (which checks that 3 days is passed and status is not set to 1 yet) and create proper index then the event procedure will need in less than a second to complete. If you're afraid nevertheless then you may additionally check that previous event procedure has finished its work, and skip current event if not. PS. One of my systems uses 5-second event procedure, and my procedure is more complex - and I have no any problem nevertheless.

Comment: @Akina thanks alot for this